# Convetir nvarchar a datetime

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla con muchos registros, cuando se creó la tabla se utilizó un campo tipo `nvarchar` para almacenar la fecha y la hora (desconozco por que no se utilizó `datetime`) el caso es que necesito convertir esos valores en `datetime` y no he podido ni con `convert` ni con `cast`, los valores se guardan en el siguiente formato:

```
20140120201508
```

Representando como `yyyymmddHHmmSS`.

¿Como puedo realizar esta conversion?

Estoy utilizando SQL server 2012.

Gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 2):

puedes realizar la conversión mediante la siguiente consulta (Suponiendo tu columna se llame "fecha"):

```
  Select convert(datetime,((left(fecha,8))+' ' + substring(fecha,9,2) 
  + ':' + substring(fecha,11,2) + ':' + substring(fecha,13,2) + '.000'),113) from Tabla
```

---

---

Pero si quieres extraer por separado el año,mes,dia,hora,minuto y segundo, tendrías que anteponer el tipo en la sentencia del DATEPART, por ejemplo para AÑO:

```
Select datepart(YEAR, convert(datetime,((left(fecha,8))+' ' 
+ substring(fecha,9,2) + ':' + substring(fecha,11,2) + ':' 
+ substring(fecha,13,2) + '.000'),113)) from Tabla
```

Solo tendrías que cambiar el tipo **YEAR** por el que quieras (**Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second**)

Answer (score 1):

bienvenido a SOes

```
/*Obtenemos todos los datos por separado*/
declare @anio nvarchar(4) = substring('20140120201508',1,4)
declare @mes nvarchar(2) = substring('20140120201508',5,2)
declare @dia nvarchar(2) = substring('20140120201508',7,2)
declare @hora nvarchar(2) = substring('20140120201508',9,2)
declare @minuto nvarchar(2) = substring('20140120201508',11,2) 
declare @segundo nvarchar(2) = substring('20140120201508',13,2)
/*Le damos el formato que buscamos*/
declare @cadenaAFormatear nvarchar(20) = concat(@anio,'-',@mes,'-', @dia,' ',@hora,':',@minuto,':',@segundo)
select FORMAT(cast(@cadenaAFormatear as datetime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as FechaFormateada
/*Sin tantas variables*/
declare @cadenaAFormatear2 nvarchar(20) = concat(substring('20140120201508',1,4),'-',substring('20140120201508',5,2),'-', substring('20140120201508',7,2),' ',substring('20140120201508',9,2),':',substring('20140120201508',11,2) ,':',substring('20140120201508',13,2))
select FORMAT(cast(@cadenaAFormatear2 as datetime),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as FechaFormateada2
```

Para mayor información sobre el trabajo con los formatos de fechas, visita https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx