# Cambiar formato de fecha a una columna tipo date sql server

Tags: sql-server

Cuando yo guardo una fecha en el formato `dd-mm-yyyy` a una tabla con un campo tipo date de SQL Server, se guarda como `yyyy-mm-dd` hasta ahí todo bien, yo quiero guardar una fecha en el formato `mm-dd-yyyy` como utilizan en Estados Unidos, al guardar esto, me sale que la fecha está mal formada. Entiendo que es porque el campo solo admite fechas en formato `dd-mm-yyyy`.

¿Cómo hago para que mi campo de tipo date pueda guardar una fecha en el formato `mm-dd-yyyy` ?

Ya probé cambiándole de idioma a la base de datos (Inglés) y poniendo intercalación Latín General 100.

Comment: Si el tipo de datos es `DATE` en SQL Server, entonces es importante que sepas que se guarda **sin formato**, simplemente se te está **mostrando** en formato yyyy-mm-dd, pero no está así en la base de datos

Comment: creo que esta respuesta que hice hace un tiempo te puede ser de utilidad http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18146/822

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda ahora se que se guarda sin formato. Mi duda iba mas por que estoy haciendo una aplicación para alguien en Estados Unidos y mi control en el front end de la aplicación permite seleccionar la fecha en el.formato mm/dd/yyyy , cuando guardo esta fecha en la.base de datos en el campo de tipo date me sale error relacionado a que la cadena no tiene el.formato correcto. Sin embargo, cuando utilizo un control que me.permite seleccionar fechas en el.formato dd/mm/yyyy me guarda sin problemas en la base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según tu comentario a la respuesta de Andoni Alda, parece que tu error está más en la grabación que en la consulta, es decir, estás intentando grabar un string en lugar de un DateTime. Puede que funcione en tu ordenador cuando lo grabas como dd/mm/yyyy en formato string porque tu servidor de base de datos está configurado para Español y por tanto no te da problemas pero al grabar como mm/dd/yyyy te puedes encontrar con fechas del tipo 03/31/2016 que te van a devolver una excepción (aparte que el resto de fechas estarán mal grabadas).

Si estás recuperando la fecha de un control tipo DatePicker o similar, el valor que te devuelve ya es un DateTime y es éste el que deberías grabar sin formatearlo previamente. Si no es así y estás obteniendo la cadena de un archivo o similar siempre puedes convertirla a DateTime utilizando un método Parse o TryParse:

```
 DateTime dtmDate = DateTime.Parse(strFecha);
```

Una vez que tienes un dateTime, no hace falta que lo vuelvas a convertir a cadena, simplemente utiliza parámetros del Command en tu grabación. Es decir, en lugar de:

```
string strSQL = string.format("INSERT INTO tabla (Fecha) VALUES {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", dtmDate);

using (SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    { command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConnection);
        objConnection.Open();
        command.Execute(strSQL);
    }
```

Utiliza parámetros:

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO tabla (Fecha) VALUES @FE_Fecha";
using (SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{ command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConnection);
  command.Parameters.Add("@FE_Fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime);
  command.Parameters["@FE_Fecha"].Value = dtmDate;
  objConnection.Open();
  command.Execute();
}
```

Donde @FE_Fecha es el parámetro que SQL Server va a utilizar como fecha.

Nota: He escrito el código sin probar, consulta la [MSDN](http://[https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) para obtener más información.

Nota 2: Otra opción que he utilizado hace tiempo si no quieres utilizar parámetros (que no entendería) es grabar a partir de una cadena es hacerlo en formato ODBC canónico, es decir: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (2016-12-03 19:23:00 por ejemplo)

Answer (score 2):

Las fechas (tipo Date, DateTime y similares) no se guardan con ningún formato en el motor de base de datos. En la base de datos se almacena de manera binaria.

### Representación Interna

De hecho, para el curioso, [se sabe](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/) que SQL Server para el tipo de dato DateTime almacena la fecha en una secuencia de 8 bytes. Divididos en dos números de 4 bytes, el primero indica el número de días transcurridos desde el *epoch* (1 de enero de 1900), y el otro almacena la cantidad de *ticks de reloj* transcurridos desde la media noche. Cada Tick del reloj mide 1/300 de milisegundo.

### Entonces ¿por qué en X herramienta lo veo con Y formato?

Cuando haces un select a la base de datos desde el *SQL Server Management Studio* u otra herramienta, es esta herramienta que estás utilizando la que va a representar esa fecha como texto y, por lo general, esta herramienta aplicará el formato de fecha de la máquina donde se ejecuta o bien el formato default configurado en la base de datos. Este *formato default* sirve solamente para que se puedan interpretar los datos de fecha que no haya de otra que representarse como texto, pero la recomendación es manejarlos como lo que son, fechas.

### Qué hago en mi lenguaje de programación

Lee la documentación. Los lenguajes que proveen interfaces de alto nivel con SQL server, generalmente te van a devolver ese dato en una variable con un tipo de dato *fecha* nativo del lenguaje, y a partir de allí de nuevo eres tu el responsable de darle una representación textual.

### Pero yo necesito que el SQL server me devuelva la fecha en X formato

No lo recomiendo, pero si no tienes de otra, pídele a SQL Server que te devuelva no una fecha, sino un texto. Para tener cierto control sobre el formato, utiliza la función [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), así:

```
select convert(varchar(20), MiFecha, 101)
  from MiTabla;
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar con esto:

```
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106), ' ', '/')
```

O usar format:

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyy/mm/dd') as date
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda ahora se que se guarda sin formato. Mi duda iba mas por que estoy haciendo una aplicación para alguien en Estados Unidos y mi control en el front end de la aplicación permite seleccionar la fecha en el.formato mm/dd/yyyy , cuando guardo esta fecha en la.base de datos en el campo de tipo date me sale error relacionado a que la cadena no tiene el.formato correcto. Sin embargo, cuando utilizo un control que me.permite seleccionar fechas en el.formato dd/mm/yyyy me guarda sin problemas en la base de datos. Debería formatear la fecha en mi aplicación antes de guardarla?