# Error al insertar una fecha con formato en un campo de tipo DATE SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un campo de tipo date que me guarda correctamente de esta forma

[image: imagen de campo de tabla]

yo quiero guardarlo con el siguiente formato "22/07/2019"

pero me sale error, ¿que esta mal en mi query?

```
update Tb_Licencia SET Fech_Activacion = convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),103) WHERE Codi_Licencia = 42;
```

este error es el que me sale:

[image: error]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cambiar formato de fecha a una columna tipo date sql server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24415/cambiar-formato-de-fecha-a-una-columna-tipo-date-sql-server)

Comment: Adicional: La fecha en SQL Server no se almacena con formato alguno. El formato se utiliza para visualizar los datos, y puede ser prácticamente cualquiera. Te recomiendo leer [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24478/21) a la pregunta referenciada en el voto de cierre. Un saludo.

Comment: Una columna de tipo DATE o DATETIME no maneja ningún formato. Si intentas salvar un dato fecha indicando un formato que no sea el ISO, lo probable ES que el motor te dé un error, imagina una cadena cómo 03/01/2019 ¿eS el 3 de enero, o el primero de marzo?, es complejo, podría ser la configuración regional del motor o bien la del propio dato. Es por eso que la única forma válida de indicar una fecha en cualquier tipo de consulta es usar el formato ISO no ambiguo yyyy-mm-dd (los separadores son opcionales). Revisa el enlace que te pasaron más arriba.